# Deeplabv3, Restoring from checkpoint failed during visualization

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a custom dataset using deeplabv3 and xception_71 as backbone. I can train the model without problem but was unable to visualize it using vis.py. It seems that the problem is about restoring the weights. But I am not sure why, any thoughts? Thanks!

train config:

```
python deeplab/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --num_clones=1 \
    --training_number_of_steps=50000 \
    --learning_rate_decay_step=500 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --model_variant="xception_71" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
   --train_crop_size="321,321" \
    --train_batch_size=5\
    --dataset="mydata" \
    --fine_tune_batch_norm=False \
    --initialize_last_layer=False \
    --last_layers_contain_logits_only=True\
    --tf_initial_checkpoint="/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/deeplab/datasets/xception_71/model.ckpt" \
    --train_logdir="/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/train_log5" \
    --dataset_dir='/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/data/tfrecord'
```

vis.py config

```
python deeplab/vis.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --vis_split="val" \
    --model_variant="xception_71" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --vis_crop_size="513,513" \
    --dataset="mydata" \
    --colormap_type="pascal" \
    --checkpoint_dir="/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/train_log5" \
    --vis_logdir="/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/vis_log5" \
    --dataset_dir="/mnt/af13d04a-f110-4c8a-a92f-a25808fe65a6/yukming/Tensorflow_ecg_deeplab/data/tfrecord"
```

Error code:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,1280,256] rhs shape= [1,1,2048,256]
         [[node save/Assign_39 (defined at /home/medicine/Envs/tf_segmentation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
         [[save/RestoreV2/_720]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,1280,256] rhs shape= [1,1,2048,256]
         [[node save/Assign_39 (defined at /home/medicine/Envs/tf_segmentation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Comment: See in the first line of error, it is written that `Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.` So you might have been trained or changed the graph after saving the biases and weights, so your saved model and your code model is not matching. Try doing all the training before and then save it. Then you can load it without any error, but  you have to load it at the first

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not exactly sure what you mean. the train.py will save the graph after training right? I didn't edit the script. And what do you mean by "load it at the first"?

Comment: you need to use 2 scripts, in `training.py`, you have to just train and save the model, and for the second script in the same directory, just write a simple code to load your data and do whatever you wanted to do with it. You can also make it easy by opening the second script by the end of `training.py` by using `os.open()` or something like that. Make sure you give a try and except statement in the training script, as you don't need to train again and again, and if trained model is found, run the second script. Also make sure that you save the model just before running the second script.

Comment: you must not have any code related to the instance of trained model after saving it, as this might causing you the error, saving and loading the model are the last lines of code for any ML or AI program.